# Running manually installed compiler with sudo doesn't work, but as root it does

Tags: sudo

This command is working ok while logged as regular user or as root, but it does not work when using `sudo`:

```
arm-linux-gcc --v
```

not working:

```
sudo arm-linux-gcc --v
```

The error I get is

```
sudo: arm-linux-gcc: command not found
```

Output requested in comments:

```
$ which arm-linux-gcc
/opt/ARM/toolschain/4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-gcc
$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin‌​:/bin
```

Comment: Define *"not working"* - if you mean the command is not found, it's probably because you installed arm-linux-gcc somewhere that's not on sudo's `secure-path`. Why do you need to compile stuff as root anyway?

Comment: not working means  sudo: arm-linux-gcc: command not found. I have some problems compiling project in eclipse with a Makefile I wrote ... please read this thread- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294848/makefile-project-in-eclipse

Comment: What is the output of `which arm-linux-gcc` and `sudo env | grep PATH`?

Comment: which arm-linux-gcc output is: /opt/ARM/toolschain/4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-gcc  and  sudo env | grep PATH output: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: @ByteCommander info was added. Would you like to answer or suggest a dupe? I think the problem is clear now!